# Blob property - Is there a better way of picking from this collection other than through a ForEach loop?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I have the following code which gets a collection of the properties of a blob and then uses a foreach loop to locate the selected property value. Is there a bettwer that does not involve looping through the collection in PowerShell 7

```
$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx  
ForEach ($Blob in $Blobs){
    if($Blob.Name.IndexOf($blobName) -ge 0)
    {          
        if (Get-Member -InputObject $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties -Name $blobPropertyName -MemberType Property) {
            $retValue = $Blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.$blobPropertyName
            break;
        }            
    } else{
        Write-Host "Blob not found!"
    }
}
```

Comment: You could offload the looping to `Where-Object`: `$Blobs |Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$blobName*"}` - it's not clear why you're dynamically trying to "discover" the properties of the `Properties` object though?

Comment: a test needs to check the state of a property on the blob.

Comment: Much better/faster/efficient to test for a specific concrete type then, ie, `{$_.Name -like "*$blobName*" -and $_.ICloudBlob -is [Expected.BlobType]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```sh
(Get-AzStorageBlob -Blob "*$blobName*" -Container $containerName -Context $ctx).
  ICloudBlob.Properties.$blobPropertyName
```

- [`Get-AzStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob)'s `-Blob` parameter accepts [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), so you don't have to manually loop over all blobs to find the one(s) of interest.
- Note that the command would also work if wildcard `"*$blobName*"` matched *multiple* blobs, because PowerShell, since v3, has a feature called [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), which is ability to access a member (a property or a method) on a *collection* and have it implicitly applied to *each of its elements*, with the *results getting collected in an array*.
- As long as `Set-StrictMode` is *off* (by default) or set to `-Version 1` at the highest, the above will simply return `$null` if either no matching blob exists or if matching blobs don't have the targeted property.